# How can I use attributes directly in methods of Javascript prototype?

Tags: javascript, object, methods, attributes, prototype

I am used to coding with objects in different languages such as Java, Python, …
I have never used JavaScript objects before and I am stuck with a problem: I don't know how to use attributes in methods.

I have done the following but perhaps it's not the correct way:

```js
function test() {
  this.un = 1;
  this.deux = 2;
  this.sum = 1;

  add = function() {
    this.sum = this.un + this.deux;
  }
}

var test = new test();
console.log(test.sum); // res : 1
test.add;
console.log(test.sum); // res : 1 and not 3 as like i want
```

Comment: If you use `this.add = function...` and call `test.add()`, then you'll get 3

Comment: Call functions using brackets.  `test.add()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call add as the method and declare it with this.add, like in the code snipet I posted:

```js
function test() {
  this.un = 1;
  this.deux = 2;
  this.sum = 1;

  this.add = function() {
    this.sum = this.un + this.deux;
  }
}

var obj = new test();
console.log(obj.sum); // res : 1
obj.add();
console.log(obj.sum); // res : 3
```

Comment: Indeed, i just forget ```this.``` when i write my question...Sorry :/

Comment: It happens :) For the record, I didn't downvote you, no need to apologize...
Also, can you accept the answer that solves your problem?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function test() {
  this.un = 1;
  this.deux = 2;
  this.sum = 1;

  this.add = function() {
    this.sum = this.un + this.deux;
  }
}

var test = new test();
console.log(test.sum); // res : 1
test.add();
console.log(test.sum); // res : 1 and not 3 as like i want
```